# parEvalMap with buffering

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm interested in a version of parEvalMap with a bounded buffer so that it will keep progressing the underlying stream as long as its buffer is not full.

What I mean is onsidering a stream of values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...] with a parallelism of 4 and a buffer size of 6 would mean:

- Start evaluating items 1,2,3,4 in parallel.
- When the inner IO action for item 1 returns, push the resutl on the output, buffer remains empty, start processing item 5
- When the inner IO action for item 3 returns, put the result in the buffer (3->result), and start processing item 6
- When the inner IO action for item 5 returns, put the result in the buffer (3->f(3), 5->f(5)), start processing item 7
- When the inner IO action for item 2 returns, push f(2) and f(3) on the output, buffer is 5-> f(5), start processing item 8
- Whenever the buffer reaches its size, processing parallelism decreases until the first item being processed returns and/or the batch size decreases.

Any idea if there is such a combinator, or what would be a good approach to implement it?

The problem we are trying to solve is to be able to process a stream of messages/items where the processing of some items take a lot longer than the average. With normal parEvalMap this slows down processing because once we have a slow request running and then even though the next N-1 requests have already returned, parEvalMap will not start processing the next request because it is bounded by its paralellism, and can't continue because it's waiting for the result of the "slow" item.

I'd like to be able to save the 2,3,4,..n results in a buffer, and continue with max paralellism, and emit all results once the slow request completes.

With parEvalMapUnordered the maximum number of paralellism is kept because the results are returned out-of-order, but with parEvalMap a slow request would halt the processing. I'd like to lift this restriction by introducing a result buffer.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the purpose of your buffer? This sounds like you are trying to implement backpressure on top of **fs2**... which already has back pressure. Anyways, maybe what you want is to push things into a bounded queue?

Comment: For me it sounds as if author assumed that `parEvalMap` performs parallelism by allowing values to be emitted out of original order, so there has to be some buffor added to restore the order (keeping things in memory until the first value leave it and allow entering a new one, etc). Thing is [the docs reads: *Like `Stream.evalMap`, but will evaluate effects in parallel, emitting the results downstream in the same order as the input stream.*](https://github.com/typelevel/fs2/blob/41521428769dda218863e2d26c322a48c64ba1c9/core/shared/src/main/scala/fs2/Stream.scala#L2156C7-L2158C51).

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I've edited the question and added clarification at the end

Comment: You may want to ask in their official **Discord** server: https://discord.com/channels/632277896739946517/632310980449402880

Comment: Does the built in `prefetch` combinator solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up rolling my own, using a `Semaphore` (to control buffer size),`zipWithIndex` to have the ability to restore ordering of results after executing them with `parEvalMapUnordered` to execute without stalling in case of outliers, and afterwards collecting the results into a HashMap[Long, Result] in `scanChunks`. I'm not sure if I can share code publicly, I'll try to get permission and do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, I think this is all you need:

```
stream
  .parEvalMapUnordered(4)(elem => process(elem))
```

> With normal parEvalMap this slows down processing because once we have a slow request running and then even though the next N-1 requests have already returned, parEvalMap will not start processing the next request because it is bounded by its paralellism

This specifically is what the *Unordered version of the method is for - your results come out in arbitrary order, but it won't wait for slow element results, it will just keep going.

I'm not aware of a version that's in between, ie waiting a little bit but not much. In practice it shouldn't matter much

Comment: Thanks for your input. It matters when there are outliers in the time `process(elem)` takes to execute. If one request takes a lot longer then others that are running in parallel, it can stall the stream until the outlier completes.

Comment: Right, that's the exact thing that `Unordered` prevents

Comment: But it doesn't keep ordering

Comment: Try using `prefetchN` with the normal `parEvalMap`